# Helm3 Using Lookup Function to Load a Variable

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am currently attempting to use the lookup function via Helm 3.1 to load a variable during installation.

```
{{ $ingress := (lookup "v1" "Ingress" "mynamespace" "ingressname").status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].hostname }}
```

Of course, this returns, "bad character [." If I remove it, it returns "nil pointer evaluating interface {}.loadBalancer".

Is what I am attempting to do even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to use "normal" array indexing syntax, but helm charts use "golang templates" and thus array indexing is done via [the `index` function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#index)

```yaml
{{ $ingress := (index (lookup "v1" "Ingress" "mynamespace" "ingressname").status.loadBalancer.ingress 0).hostname }}
```

---

after further thought, I can easily imagine that `nil` pointer error happening during `helm template` runs, since [`lookup` returns `map[]` when running offline](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/9309#issuecomment-771579215)

In that case, you'd want to use the `index` function for **every** path navigation:

```yaml
{{ $ingress := (index (index (index (index (index (lookup "v1" "Ingress" "mynamespace" "ingressname") "status") "loadBalancer")  "ingress") 0) "hostname") }}
```

or, assert the lookup is in "offline" mode and work around it:

```yaml
      {{ $ingress := "fake.example.com" }}
      {{ $maybeLookup := (lookup "v1" "Ingress" "mynamespace" "ingressname") }}
      {{ if $maybeLookup }}
      {{   $ingress = (index $maybeLookup.status.loadBalancer.ingress 0).hostname }}
      {{ end }}
```

Comment: Appreciate the response mdaniel. I tried it out but got the below. 

**Error I receive now:**
`: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.loadBalancer`

I can confirm that the ingress is indeed in the namespace I am referencing and I do have the correct name for the namespace/ingress. A JSON path via kubectl returns it. 

**Example of working kubectl:**

`kubectl get ingress/ingressname -n namespace -o jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].hostname}"`

Comment: In that case I'm sorry that I deleted my comment from earlier, because you may benefit from seeing what helm sees by `{{ $x := (lookup "v1" "Ingress" "myns" "thename") | toJson }}{{ fail $x }}`, and then run `helm install` because the `lookup` only contacts k8s during _live_ operations, `helm template` nor `helm install --dry-run` won't do it

Comment: mcdaniel, thanks. `{{ $ingress := ( index (lookup "networking.k8s.io/v1" "Ingress" "mynamespace" "ingress").status.loadBalancer.ingress 0).hostname }}` Your answer is correct, my issue is I was calling the wrong API. I had **v1** when it should have been **networking.k8s.io/v1**. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm sorry I didn't spot that earlier -- and I'm glad you finally got it to work!

Comment: No worries. I appreciate your time and insight. Definitely lead to the resolution of the problem.